How to send NULL value from an R script to a REAL type column in SQL
I defined variables as:
OVERLAY_LEVEL <- "overlay"
OVERLAY_LEVEL_NAME <- "OVERLAY_LEVEL"
BASE_WEDGE <- "base"
OVERLAY_TYPE <- "Get_OVERLAY_TYPE"
OVERLAY_MODE <- "Get_OVERLAY_MODE_PCST"
OUTLOOK_MONTH <- 2024-03-01  UTC
START_DATE <- 2024-04-01 UTC
END_DATE <- 2024-04-30UTC
OIL <- 200
GAS <- 200
COMMENTS <- "Get_comments"
NGL <- NULL
I build a dataframe as:
df.base <- data.frame( OVERLAY_LEVEL
                       ,OVERLAY_LEVEL_NAME
                       ,BASE_WEDGE
                       ,OVERLAY_TYPE
                       ,OVERLAY_MODE
                       ,OUTLOOK_MONTH
                       ,START_DATE
                       ,END_DATE
                       ,OIL
                       ,GAS
                       ,NGL
                       ,COMMENTS
                       )

The SQL table is defined as:
CREATE TABLE TEST(
    [OVERLAY_LEVEL] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [OVERLAY_LEVEL_NAME] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [BASE_WEDGE] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [OVERLAY_TYPE] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [OUTLOOK_MONTH] [date] NOT NULL,
    [START_DATE] [date] NOT NULL,
    [END_DATE] [date] NOT NULL,
    [OIL] [real] NULL,
    [GAS] [real] NULL,
    [COMMENTS] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [OVERLAY_MODE] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [NGL] [real] NULL
) 

But I get an error as:
Error in data.frame(OVERLAY_LEVEL, OVERLAY_LEVEL_NAME, BASE_WEDGE, OVERLAY_TYPE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

Basically, I want to set the NGL column to NULL (no value) in SQL.
How do I achieve that?
Setting NGL <- NA sends the NGL value to 0 which is not what I want.
Code for inserting data to SQL:
  con <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server; Server=test;Uid=xx; Pwd=xxx") 
#Save the changes to the database

startIndex <- 1
insertsRemaining <- nrow(df.base)
 
    while(insertsRemaining>0) #INSERT DIRECTLY INTO THE OVERLAYS TABLE
    {
      stopIndex <- startIndex + min(insertsRemaining, 1000) - 1
      dfLimit <-  df.base[startIndex:stopIndex,]
      
      values <- paste("('",dfLimit$OVERLAY_LEVEL,"','",dfLimit$OVERLAY_LEVEL_NAME,"','",
                      dfLimit$BASE_WEDGE,"','",
                      dfLimit$COMMENTS,"','",
                      dfLimit$OVERLAY_TYPE,"','", 
                      dfLimit$OVERLAY_MODE,"','",
                      dfLimit$OUTLOOK_MONTH, "','",
                      dfLimit$START_DATE,"','" ,
                      dfLimit$END_DATE,"','" ,
                      dfLimit$OIL,"','" ,
                      dfLimit$GAS,"','",
                      dfLimit$NGL,"')", sep="", collapse=",")
      
      sqlINSERT_command = sqlQuery(con, paste("INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE ([OVERLAY_LEVEL],
                                              [OVERLAY_LEVEL_NAME],[BASE_WEDGE],[COMMENTS],[OVERLAY_TYPE],[OVERLAY_MODE],[OUTLOOK_MONTH],[START_DATE],[END_DATE],[OIL],[GAS],[NGL]) VALUES",values))
      
      startIndex <- startIndex + nrow(dfLimit)
      insertsRemaining <- insertsRemaining - nrow(dfLimit)
  
 
  #browser()
}


You haven't actually included any code which does any type of SQL DML.  You need to include that R code.

@TimBiegeleisen added it. Didn't think it was needed.

This is a correct answer which however solves the problem on the SQL side.  Appreciate that omitting a column from an INSERT statement will result in NULL being inserted for that column.  So, you could just omit NGL from the select list to get the behavior you want.
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE ([OVERLAY_LEVEL], [OVERLAY_LEVEL_NAME], [BASE_WEDGE], [COMMENTS],
    [OVERLAY_TYPE], [OVERLAY_MODE], [OUTLOOK_MONTH], [START_DATE], [END_DATE], [OIL], [GAS])
VALUES
    -- tuples not including any value for NGL
  


oh darn. that was simple. thanks!

BTW...there is probably an R way of doing this which includes NGL, but that would take some research.
